# How to automatically launch an app without a button

Tags: android

Is it possible to launch my app's code without using a button?

I would like my app to 'just do it' when someone clicks the app icon.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity is automatically being launched if clicked on your app icon.

In the onCreate of your Activity you can send Intent to start another Activity.

If you mean an Icon in your app, see xjaphx answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `OnClickListener` to your icon, which would be an `ImageView`.